# Derserialize JSON.NET With Unknown RootObject Key

Tags: c#, json.net, steam-web-api

```
{
"578080": {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "type": "game",
        "name": "PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS",
        "steam_appid": 578080,
        "required_age": 0,
        "is_free": false,
        }
    }
}
```

This is from the Steam API.  As you can see the root key the ID itself, so I don't know how to deserialize this to an object. I've seen other questions regarding unknown property names, but can't seem to apply those solutions for when the root name is unknown.

Comment: I assume that ID is a player ID in steam right? Do you save it somewherE?

Comment: No it's the AppID.  So it's different for every call, hence my confusion on how to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to *Deserialize* to `Dictionary`

**Classes**

```
public class Data
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int steam_appid { get; set; }
    public int required_age { get; set; }
    public bool is_free { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SomeClass>>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks the solution is much easier than I realized.  BTW is using deserialize like a verb as I did considered incorrect nomenclature?

Comment: If you are talking about the naming yeah it is

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about making POCO models for your deserialized data and just want to grab some of the properties using a `dynamic`, you can use `JsonExtensionData` to get a `JToken` of the relevant subobject:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> ExtensionData {get; set;}
}

dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json).ExtensionData.Single().Value;
Console.WriteLine(obj.success);
Console.WriteLine(obj.data.name);
```

This approach would be particularly useful if you could reuse `Foo` across several different types of responses since it doesn't care at all about the object schema.

Comment: I actually tried the [JsonExtensionData]  with a class exactly how you have it but didn't do '.ExtenstionData.Single().

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous type deserialization to parse JSON data like this, without creating classes. I assumed there is only one Id("578080") present in your data.If more Id's present, you can create an array for those Id's. Hope It Works.

```
 var finalResult=JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(
        yourdata,  // input
        new 
        {
          Id= 
          {
            new
            { 
              success="", data=""
            }
          }
        }
      ); 

console.write(finalResult.Id);// getting Id 578080
console.write(finalResult.Id.success);
console.write(finalResult.Id.data.type);
```